# Zend Layout Placeholder?

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to create a sidebar in my layout that has the behavior of a placeholder. I want to be able to define the contents of this placeholder once per controller. So every controller can add custom content to the sidebar but without the need to define it in any view.

I am kind of confused on how to go about that with Zend_Layout. Any help?

Comment: I get that you can do something like: $this->layout()->sidebar to inject content into the layout but I want to make the content the same on every view for each controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a `postDispatch()` call to each controller?

```
public function postDispatch()
{
    // code to populate/activate your placeholder
    $this->view->placeholder('xxx');
}
```

This function will be called after your action completes. For more info, see [Pre- and Post-Dispatch Hooks](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.prepostdispatch).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried something similar. Here is what you can do.

Place this type of code in the layout.phtml script file. Somewhere near the top. You don't have to but this way you 'know' what placeholders you're using. Doing this in the layout is also a good idea because you can wrap html divs are whatever here and not worry about it in the views. The views can just worry about the content. After this, you can add content to the placeholders from the controllers and the views.

```
$this->placeholder('blah');
$this->placeholder('sidebar');
$this->placeholder('blunk');
```

If you don't want to create them in your layout, then you can do it in the controller like so,

```
$this->view->placeholder( 'sidebar');
```

.

Now, you can either put content into it in the controller, or in the view script. Its a better idea to add the content in the view though.

In the layout you can then just echo the placeholders like so

`echo $this->placeholder->( 'sidebar' );`

All the views are executed BEFORE the layout is executed so any placeholders created by the views will be available to the layout to print out.

Also, controllers don't HAVE placeholders. Only views, and by extension layout, have placeholders like this so you have to declare them somewhere. Even if you declare them in the controller they still 'belong' to the view object.

I don't know if this helps at all but good luck. Tell me what you think.

Comment: Hmm... I was hoping there was a way to template it in markup.
.net MVC has a way to do that but I forgot what it is called. I guess I could just put the markup in the layout and have it decide which version to display from what is passed through the placeholder.

Comment: I don't think that I quite understand what you mean then. You want to template the markup output IN the markup? I think that there might be some MVC magic going on in .net but in PHP you'll have to do more of the work yourself.

If EVERY controller is showing the same sidebar then it would suffice to put <code>$this->placeholder( 'name' )->append( $this->view->render( 'scriptfile.phtml' ) )</code> into the init method of your controllers.

Comment: They are called Editor Templates in .net.

Answer (score 0):

i have just implemented a solution to this that should work for most uses.

I store all of my placeholder.phtml files in the following dir:
/views/scripts/_placeholder

Within the placeholder i create directories for each Controller / Action that has a placeholder (as well as ROOT stuff). I then create a file for each placeholder.

e.g. Placeholder = sidebar. Controller = user / action = view

for the above we would store a file here:

views/scripts/_placeholder/user/view/sidebar.phtml

note: within the sidebar.phtml you will need to add : $this->placeholder("sidebar")->captureStart() and captureEnd();

if the plugin sees this file it will render it. If it doesnt find one then it wont.

Additionally the plugin will also look for the following and pull that in first:

views/scripts/_placeholder/sidebar.phtml

I can post the plugin if you want.

The only issue i have is i would like to now know if a placeholder has any data in it. That way i can create some layouts that are clever and will render what needs. DOes anyone know how to do this?